# Laravel: Check if User is an admin using isAdmin column?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm really new to laravel and have been reading the documentations and tutorials. I'm planning on making an app that has 2 roles, admin and user. I modified my User model to have the column 'isAdmin' with boolean value since I only need 2 roles. How do I perform a check on this attribute during auth? Thank you.

Comment: Hi Raihan, there are multiple questions in this thread. I suggest to keep 1 per thread. Please update. Based on that, I will answer/guide you.

Comment: Hi Digvijay, edited to only 1 question.

Comment: Computer Maverick's answer is promising. Please follow that. Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TO answer your question, first of all to make protect any route using the auth middleware which ensures a user is authenticated (logged in) before they can access the route, you simply need to add the auth middleware.
e.g

web.php

```
<?php
Route::middleware('auth')->group(function(){
//All Routes which needs user to be logged in
});

or 

//Individiual Route Middleware
Route::get('/path/to', 'controller@instance')->middleware('auth');
```

As for checking user role, you can basically create a middleware for this using the following steps:

1. run your php artisan make:middleware IsAdminMiddleware
2. open your IsAdminMiddleware and add this code inside the handle function:

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
            {
                if(!Auth::check()){
                    return redirect()->route('login');
                }
        
                if(Auth::user()->isAdmin == true){
                    return $next($request);
                }
        
                return redirect()->back()->with('unauthorised', 'You are 
                  unauthorised to access this page');
            }
```

Comment: Actually have a follow up question. How do I then group the routes if I have separate routes for admin and user? My guess would be to group user routes with auth middleware and admin routes with both auth and isAdmin middleware. Is this right?

Comment: @RaihanDewana Yes you can do that.